# Conditional sed depending on backreferences identical or not

Tags: regex, sed

The following `sed` command:

```
sed -E -e 's#µ(bar)>([^|¢]+)\|([^µ|]+)¢#:\1:`\3 <\2>`#g'
```

- takes what is between `µ` and `¢`,
- splits it in 3 back references (`\1`, `\2`, `\3`), with `>` and `|` as delimiters,
- and returns `` :\1:`\3 <\2>` ``

For instance:

```
$ sed -E -e 's#µ(bar)>([^|¢]+)\|([^µ|]+)¢#:\1:`\3 <\2>`#g' <<< "µbar>foo|baz¢"
:bar:`baz <foo>`
$ sed -E -e 's#µ(bar)>([^|¢]+)\|([^µ|]+)¢#:\1:`\3 <\2>`#g' <<< "µbar>foo|foo¢"
:bar:`foo <foo>`
```

Now, what I would like is returning only `` :\1:`\2` ``  in the case where `\3` and `\2` are identical, in order to get `` :bar:`foo` `` in the second example.

How could I achieve this result with `sed` (possibly with the help of another tool)?

### Edit 1

More generally, my real use case involves alternatives, such as the following one (only the first one needs conditional on back references):

```
sed -E -e 's#µ(bar1|bar2|bar3)>([^|¢]+)\|([^µ|]+)¢#:\1:`\3 <\2>`#g ; s#µ(bar1|bar2|bar3)>([^|¢µ]+)¢#:\1:`\2`#g'
```

The first answer from @anubhava to my first question, that didn't involve alternatives, is based on `awk`, the syntax of which being quite esoteric to my eyes :)

### Edit 2

In my original question, the first groups should not match (`[^...]`) the delimiters (`µ`, `|`, and `µ`) in order to deal with multiple occurrences of the pattern on a same line. Aside remark: the patterns may be surrounded by text and, in particular, may not be at the beginning of a line.

Moreover, I have to deal with the cases where there is no `|` delimiter (second `sed` command of my Edit 1), e.g. `µbar3>foo¢` should return `` :bar3:`foo` ``

So, a more realistic test file would be:

```
Bla bla bla µbar1>foo|baz¢ bla bla bla µbar2>foo|foo¢ bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla µbar3>foo¢ bla bla bla.
```

the expected output of which being:

```
Bla bla bla :bar1:`baz <foo>` bla bla bla :bar2:`foo` bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla :bar3:`foo` bla bla bla.
```

Comment: :) Sounds like edit 2 is enough.

Comment: @anubhava Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Perl` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\|(.+?))?¢#
    sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>") #ge' < input.txt
```

`input.txt`:

```
μbar>foo|baz¢
μbar>foo|foo¢
μbar>foo¢
Bla bla bla μbar1>foo|baz¢ bla bla bla μbar2>foo|foo¢ bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla μbar3>foo¢ bla bla bla.
```

Output:

```
:bar:`baz <foo>`
:bar:`foo`
:bar:`foo`
Bla bla bla :bar1:`baz <foo>` bla bla bla :bar2:`foo` bla bla bla.
Bla bla bla :bar3:`foo` bla bla bla.
```

- The `-pe` option tells `Perl` to process the input file line by line then
  print the each line as `sed -e` does.
- The regex `.+?` matches the substring *as short as possible* and you don't
  have to care about the `overrun` in case the input line contains multiple
  delimiters.
- The regex `(?:pattern)` is similar to the grouping `(pattern)` but
  it does not create the capture group for backreference. (meaning
  the regex generates the backrefences from `$1` to `$3` at most, not `$4`.)
- The `g` option to the regex enables the global (multiple) match.
- The `e` option allows the REPLACEMENT to be not only a string but a
  perl expression. This is a powerful feature to make the substitution
  very flexible (and hopefully readable).
- The expression `($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>"` may look
  obfuscated but it is just a conditional operator meaning *if $3 is empty
  or $2 and $3 are the same, then print $2, else print "$3 <$2>"*.

Comment: Your solution works nicely with this input. What confuses me is it doesn't work with alternatives other than `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar3` though I don't see anything specific to these strings in your Perl code: for instance, strings such as `µctanpkg>foo¢` or `µctanpkg>foo|baz¢` are missed. BTW, I don't see the point about "the regex generates the backrefences from `$1` to `$3` at most, not `$4`".

Comment: @rowboat I edited this answer in order to replace `￠` by `¢`.

Comment: @rowboat and Denis Bitouzé thank you  for pointing out and editing my answer for me! This is due to my corrupted text editor. Thanks again.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks to your correcting the character code, I have confirmed it works with the inputs `μtcanpkg>foo¢` and `μtcanpkg>foo|baz¢`.

Comment: Indeed, I guess it didn't work because of an encoding trouble. Now it works :)

Comment: Let me answer your question about the grouping and the backreferences.
If we write the regex as : `#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(\|(.+?))?¢#`, we need to use
`$1`, `$2` and `$4` to refer the matched substrings later because the outer parens of
`(\|(.+?))` uselessly consumes `$3`. That is why I used `(?:\|(.+?))`
instead.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, what I would like is returning only `` :\1:`\2` `` in the case where `\3` and `\2` are identical.

It is easier to use `awk` here like this:

```sh
cat file
µbar>foo|baz¢
µbar>foo|foo¢
```

awk command:

```sh
awk -F '[|>]+' '$1 ~ /^µ(bar1|bar2|bar3)$/ {
   sub(/¢$/, "", $3)
   print ":" substr($1, 2) ":`" ($2 != $3 ? $2 " " : "") "<" $3 ">`"
}' file

:bar:`foo <baz>`
:bar:`<foo>`
```

---

Since question has been heavily modified since posted here is a `gnu-awk` to get expected output:

```sh
awk '{
   while (match($0, /µ(bar1|bar2|bar3)>([^|¢]+)(\|([^µ|]+))?¢/, m)) { 
      printf "%s", substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) ":" m[1] ":`" (m[4] != "" ? m[4] (m[2] != m[4] ? " <" m[2] ">" : "") : m[2]) "`"
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   print ""
}' file

Bla bla bla :bar1:`baz <foo>` bla bla bla :bar2:`foo`
Bla bla bla :bar3:`foo`
```

Comment: This works nicely indeed, thanks :) The trouble now is, this was a simplified example: the actual `sed` command in my use case involves groups with alternatives: ```sed -E -e 's#µ(faquk|ctanpkg|texdoc)>([^|¢µ]+)¢#:\1:`\2`#g ; s#µ(faquk|ctanpkg|texdoc)>([^|¢]+)\|([^µ|]+)¢#:\1:`\3 <\2>`#g'` ```. And I have no idea how to deal with such alternatives with the esoteric `awk`'s syntax ;)

Comment: answer can only be based on the question so that's what it is. If you update your question with enhanced requirements then I will try to adjust it

Comment: Nice! Still an edge case my minimal example missed (sorry): I'll edit my question once again.