# During Perl substitution, increase the output with spaces in order it is of the same length as the input

Tags: regex, perl, string-length

(**Disclaimer:** I don't understand much of Perl!)

A (nice!) answer to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65202868/1682470) advised me to use (more or less) the following `perl` trick for a tricky substitution:

```
perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\&(.+?))?¢¢# sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>")#ge'
```

And, indeed, that works nicely:

```
echo "μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢" | perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\&(.+?))?¢¢# sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>")#ge'
```

returns:

```
:ctanpkg:`a4`
```

Now, I need to add at the end of this substitution as many spaces as needed in order the output string is of the same length as the input one.

How could I achieve such a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that the outstanding issue, drawing a "bounty," is the length of the repalcement string.

The problem there is the presence of Unicode characters, which are taken as bytes -- print the length of the input string and it's 19, while there are 16 (sixteen) characters in it; that's the `μ` and the two `¢`, each needing two bytes.

So add flags for [Unicode handling](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D), to decode those octets into [logical characters](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode#Extended-Grapheme-Clusters-(Logical-characters)). Also add the [utf8 pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) (via `-Mutf8` below) so that our literal characters in the source are interpreted correctly

```
echo "μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢" | perl -CSA -Mutf8 -wlnE'
    say;
    s{μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:&(.+?))?¢¢}{ 
        $r = sprintf(":%-s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>"); 
        "=" x (length($_) - length($r)) . $r }ge;
    say'
```

Can be copy-pasted as is, with multiple lines (in bash and some other shells) or used on one line.  This is with `-n` in order to print at will; remove the prints and change to `-p` as needed.

I used `=` for alignment so that it is easy to see, change as needed. If the replacement winds up longer then the [repetition operator (`x`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Multiplicative-Operators) prints a warning and returns an empty string; we can do without that warning of course but there is a question of design.

In an example in a comment the replacement string indeed ends up longer, so we need to pad the original instead, for alignment. But in the question only the replacement is printed, presumably the original being printed elsewhere -- from a program that runs this one-liner? So we need a clarification for the desired behavior of this program in such a case.

For one, then one surely won't add to the replacement string, so the statement

```
"=" x (length($_) - length($r)) . $r
```

should rather turn into something to the effect of

```
$shrank_by = length($_) - length($r);
( $shrank_by > 0 ? "=" x $shrank_by : "" ) . $r
```

Comment: Looks very nice and clever (congratulations for the Unicode characters needing two bytes!). Nevertheless, still not the same width with (OK, foolish) string such as `¥ctanpkgÞmathtex&MathtexŦ` (and `s{¥(.+?)Þ(.+?)(?:&(.+?))?Ŧ}` or even with the simple string `1ctanpkg2mathtex3Mathtex4` (and `s{1(.+?)2(.+?)(?:3(.+?))?4}`). And, sorry, I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé So ... you have in that first string  a currency sign (U+00A5 , or perhaps "full width" U+FFE5), then a little olde english (00FE) then a "Northern Sámi" character (U+0166). I know how latex packages go but is this a joke? :)  Anyway, have to see what confuses the lengths there ... so I'm doing that last sentence: printing out lengths of various parts for debugging :)  (Will remove that sentence).  That last ("simple") string -- does it start with an ASCII `1` or is that something else?  Hard to distinguish in a comment but it doesn't look like a straight `1`...?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé ... ah, got it!  In these examples the **replacements are longer** !  So what do you want to do in such a case? Your sample code only prints the replaced string so one can't fix that then (if the original is printed from somewhere else, now replacement is longer and that's that).  If you were to print both right in this one-liner (like my code does) then we can align _the original_ instead.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The replacement gets longer because in these cases (given in your comment above) your pattern ends up replacing a character with ` <$2>`, so adding three (4-1) characters.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Edited (added) commentary on such cases in the answer

Comment: About the joke, it has a tenuous link with LaTeX: I'm currently trying to convert a LaTeX FAQ made with Doluwiki to Sphinx-doc, hence with reStructuredTeXt, the latter being very fussy (fastidious?) about the length of the string in tables :). And it was a straight `1`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé "_tenuous link with LaTeX_" -- OK, I thought that there was a structural reason for such an assembly of characters :).  Good luck with the project, doesn't seem easy.  I've written a lot with Latex and certainly appreciate good docs, so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf#flags) to do that, with a pattern that uses left-justify. The length can be passed in as an argument. The pattern for that is as follows.

```
printf "<%-*s>", 6, "a";   # prints "<a     >"
```

You can get the length of the last successful match with `$&`, as documented in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$&).

```
perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\&(.+?))?¢¢# sprintf("%-*s", length($&), sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>"))#ge'
```

With your example input, this isn't visible as it's using spaces. But if we add extra `<>` to the pattern, you can see that it's working.

```
#                                                                           V     V
$ echo "μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢" | perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\&(.+?))?¢¢# sprintf("<%-*s>", length($&), sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>"))#ge'
<:ctanpkg:`a4`       >
```

This will also work for lines with multiple matches.

```
echo "μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢ μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢" | perl -pe 's#μ(.+?)>(.+?)(?:\&(.+?))?¢¢# sprintf("<%-*s>", length($&), sprintf(":%s:`%s`", $1, ($3 eq "" or $2 eq $3) ? $2 : "$3 <$2>"))#ge'
<:ctanpkg:`a4`      > <:ctanpkg:`a4`      >
```

Please note that `$&` used to incur [a performance penalty](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#Performance-issues) in older Perls. This was fixed in 5.20. Even if you are on a version below that, your use-case probably isn't impacted very much.

Comment: Sigh, I should have told that it may be more than a single occurrence of `μctanpkg>...&...¢¢` on a line. For instance, with `μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢, μctanpkg>a4wide&a4wide¢¢`, your (nice:) solution gives the wrong number of spaces.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé ah, I didn't see the `/g`. That's still possible though. GIve me a moment.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé please see my edit. This will work.

Comment: Works very nicely, now! I'm using Perl v5.32.1 so, is it enough for me to remove `length($&), `?

Comment: @Denis I only mention the Perl version because of the run-time penalty of using `$&` in older Perls. You need the `length($&) as an argument to `sprrintf` because we use that to determine the length of that pattern. Regardless of your Perl version, you must not remove that or the code will break. But on your relatively new Perl (5.32 was released in 2020) you can use `$&` without it slowing your code down.

Comment: The penalty of using `$&` was that it made all matches in the entire interpreter perform if they had captures. So there is absolutely no performance penalty of using `$&` here, even in older versions, since there are no other match or substitute operators. 5.20 eliminated the performance penalty of capturing.

Comment: Sorry for adding another request: would it possible to add the spaces before and not after the substitution?

Comment: I just found how to add the spaces before and not after the substitution: it is enough to replace `%-*s` by `%*s`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé yeah, that's right-justify.

Comment: Well... sorry but, in your solution, the input and the output are in fact not of the same length: e.g. the lengths of `μctanpkg>a4&a4¢¢` and `:ctanpkg:+a4+       ` (backticks replaced by `+)` are respectively 16 and 20 :$

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your point. Nevertheless, I love maths! :)

Comment: @simbabque Sorry but would me to add some maths? I guess I would manage, but the difficult part would be to translate them in Perl.